# I want to see 2 different overlay at the same time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

ive created an indicator which u can clearly look like this [___the indicator that ive made here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsfmz.png) but i want to see my atr look like this [i want to make like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htEAJ.png)

```
indicator("Komut dosyam",overlay = true or false)

overlay_numero=input.int(1,title="Overlay Num",options = [0,1],inline="select a number for overlay")

overlaynum(overlay_numero)=>
    ali=if overlay_numero==1
        overlay=false
    else if overlay_numero==0
        overlay=true
    ali 
.....

//none of them couldnt work as of like this
plot(ta.valuewhen(overlaynum(overlay_numero = 1) and plot_string_4=="ATR",source = atr,occurrence=0),color=color.red)
plot(ta.valuewhen(overlaynum(overlay_numero = 1) and plot_string_4=="MFI",source = mfi,occurrence=mfi_value),color=color.aqua)
plot(ta.valuewhen(overlaynum(overlay_numero = 1) and plot_string_4=="CMO",source = cmo,occurrence=0),color=color.silver)
plot(ta.valuewhen(overlaynum(overlay_numero = 1) and plot_string_4=="RSI",source = rsi,occurrence=0),color=color.blue)
plot(ta.valuewhen(overlaynum(overlay_numero = 1) and plot_string_4=="MOM",source = mom,occurrence=0),color=color.lime)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're referring to the additional chart beneath the large chart?

Comment: referring to the small ones , yes

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. One script can only work as `overlay=true` or `overlay=false`.

If you want to see the ATR value on your chart, you can plot it on the status line or data window. This way, it wouldn't mess up your chart's scale and you would still be able to see its value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

atr_val = ta.atr(14)

plot(atr_val, "ATR", color.red, display=display.data_window + display.status_line)
```

[image]

Comment: due to the amount of plot numbers, i couldnt see the values like that.for this problem i want to another function for the plots but i get an error like "cannot use plot as a local scope." how can i solve it?

Comment: Well, then maybe display it in a table?